# PGFplots axis with arrow tips at the end

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

By using the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=40,ymin=0, ymax=42, xlabel=Φρούτα,ylabel=Γάλα]
 \addplot [color=Blue] coordinates {
      (0 ,40) 
       (20, 30)
   (30, 20)
  (35, 10)
(39, 0)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'm taking the following result

[image]

However, how could I achieve the following one?
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `axis lines = middle` (see section 4.8.9 of the current version [1.8] of the pgfplots manual).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 40,
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 42, 
  axis lines = middle,
  enlargelimits = true,
  ]
 \addplot+[mark = none] coordinates {%
   (0 ,40) 
   (20, 30)
   (30, 20)
   (35, 10)
   (39, 0)};
  \node[below left] at (axis cs:0,0) {$0$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*Update* I changed the style of the axis (thanks to @Jake) so that they stick better to your example (`axis lines = left`). I added also the axis labels with the `xlabel` and `ylabel` keys. As you typed some greek letters, I used the `xits` package and compile the whole document with `lualatex`. Finally, I added some kind of label above the point `(0,40)` using the `axis cs` coordinate system. Note that any node defined inside the scope of the `axis` environment can be accessed outside of it.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin = 0,
  xmax = 40,
  ymin = 0,
  ymax = 42, 
  axis lines = left,
  xlabel = Φρούτα,
  ylabel = Γάλα
  ]
  \addplot+[mark = none] coordinates {%
    (0,40) 
    (20,30)
    (30,20)
    (35,10)
    (39,0)};
  \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:0,40);
\end{axis}
\node[above right] at (A) {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cjorseen thank you a lot. could I add over point a letter? I.e. could I node A above (0,40)? Also, how can I name the axes?

Comment: @giannis I hope I understood your request (see updated answer).

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thank you very much!